# Reset Default.aspx to reference masterpage

Tags: master-page

I have a client that have several sites in which their default.aspx either did not migrate correctly, or they customized the homepage. How can I "reset" the default.aspx to reference the masterpage that I need? It seems as though the masterpage reference was hardcoded. I don't really care about the webparts on the page as much, as long as the masterpage is right. I know how to do this using SharePoint Designer. But I wanted to know of any powershell cmdlets that will do this for me, because there are several sites that have this problem.

Masterpage reference should be "/_catalogs/masterpage/default.aspx"

[image]